# CSS: same styling for multiple elements - for naming purposes?

Tags: jquery, css, class

So, I have a pretty consistent layout for my website. As a result, I have many some classes with identical styling (mainly width, height, padding, etc.). This is mainly for two reasons:

1. It makes it easier when going through the code because some elements will have classes that can be identified.
2. Because they can be identified, it also is helpful when used with jQuery too. For instance, in some cases, I have a few identically styled divs laying on one another and I have them cycle through one by one.
3. In the case that I want to change the style to one of them (likely not sizing, but perhaps background color, font color/size, etc.), I can then target the one specifically and not have to rename it later... or create a new class to make the edit.

Is this bad practice? Will too much CSS create a far slower website? And if it is bad practice... what would you suggest is best to solve the reasons I use it. For #3, it seems creating a second class could work in those scenarios. But what about #1 and #2... is there some other type of naming convention that I should be using instead?

Comment: It depends how much you're repeating IMO. It would be great if you could post some code, but it sounds like you might want to put the repeated code into a single class, then put the differences in other classes and assign multiple classes to your elements. ie. `<div class="common red">`. See http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/multiple-classes/ . Also, note that changing inline styles is generally faster than changing classes http://jsperf.com/change-class-vs-inline-styling/3

Comment: There are many [**CSS Optimizers**](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+optimizer) or very good CSS Beautifiers you can search for, like this [**ONE**](http://www.codebeautifier.com/) that will **optimize** your CSS code to have less selectors (in which case your jQuery should use id's for the selectors) as well as making the file size smaller which reduces loading time and footprint for mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks! Okay, so it seems it would be best to consolidated some of my classes. And for the elements that need to be used with jQuery, just give them IDs so that they can be selected? Forgive me for this question... but can I give an element an ID or class that doesn't have related CSS styling and is ONLY used for jQuery? Or is that frowned upon? Because if that's the best way then in some cases I will have the following: generic classes that define a broad number of elements on multiple pages. When specific styling is needed, use a 2nd class/id and another as a jQuery selector (if necessary).

Comment: Per your 3 questions: Yes, Yes, No. It's normal to use a id or class name for an element that has no style, to use as you need to, for a jQuery selector. There are quite a few tutorials on learning jQuery, and the jQuery website has an [**Introduction Section**](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery) you can read about to learn more. Cheers!